# Google Fonts not being loaded in Rails development, but works fine in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, font-awesome, google-font-api

I imported a font and it worked on my machine because I had the font installed and I didn't even notice that it wasn't being loaded from Google Fonts. It worked in production too, so there was nothing to tip me off that it wasn't being loaded in development until I had my brother open the site to test something for me. I've tried multiple different things to fix this and there's some odd behaviours. This is the top of my application.scss right now:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 *
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@200;400;600;900&display=swap');
```

If I move my google fonts @import to the absolute top of the file, above even the comment, it loads the font, but also [completely breaks a lot of the page styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oLn2.jpg).

I noticed a difference between the production and development css when I looked. [The production css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVgHT.png) had the google fonts @import before the font-awesome stuff, whereas [in development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUOWd.png), the @import came after the font-awesome stuff, so I tried removing font-awesome and the google fonts loaded completely fine. However I still need font-awesome, I can't just get rid of it.

I know the easiest solution would be to use the  tag in the layout since I know that works, but I prefer to use the css and I thought it would be better if I knew what was going on regardless. I've looked for a while but I haven't managed to find anyone with a similar problem. Anyone have any clue what is going on?

Comment: You can try precompiling the assets in development.

Comment: Ah, just tried and it didn't work. Regardless, I appreciate the help.